# Set the default propel connection for entire php process

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

Propel 1.6 and Symfony 1.4

I'm looking for a way to programmatically set the default propel connection for the length of an entire php process.  The issue is that I'm using an alternative db for testing purposes and I have a good deal of code that doesn't pass the PropelPDO object currently.

Can this be done?  Any tips?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. I've added your answer as community wiki, and reverted the update. If you self-answer (it is encouraged) then just add an answer yourself, and tick it to remove it from unanswered lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use environments in your `databases.yml`?

```
dev:
  propel:
    class:        sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname:  DebugPDO
    etc, etc


stage:
  propel:
    class:        sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname:  PropelPDO
  etc, etc


prod:
  propel:
    class:        sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname:  PropelPDO
  etc, etc
```

Comment: yea, I did that, but the issue is that you have to pass the connection to any method that needs to perform a query.  Whereas, if you could rely on the default, you wouldn't have to do this.  And, in our case, case, update part of our models.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution to this was to use the following, pretty clean and sweet:

```
//override the "default" "propel" dsn and set it to our testing db!
\Propel::setConnection(
    "propel",
    Propel::getConnection(SqliteSetup::$databaseName)
);
```